# Where can I download the "FlipNoteControllerExample" from WWDC 2011 "Implementing UIViewController Containtment"

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Where can I download the "FlipNoteControllerExample" from WWDC 2011 "Implementing UIViewController Contentment"？ It does not include sample code linkage on Apple WDC page:

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.  However, there are other good examples...

Apple WWDC 2012 session on "The Evolution of View Controllers on iOS" example code here:
https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_sample_code/wwdc_2012_session_code.dmg

There's also a good example here:
https://github.com/toolmanGitHub/stackedViewControllers

and here:
http://www.merowing.info/2012/02/uiviewcontroller-containment/